# Doubts about the file I/O

Tags: c++, file-io

Currently I'm just getting started on c++ and wanted to take a dive into file I/O so I searched for some random code and typed it to see if it works and how it works. But I ran into some problems that myself cannot understand.

```
#include <fstream>  //for file processing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> //to_string

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 ) 
{
    cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments" << endl;
    return 1;
}
//open file at argv[1] ( should be our input file )
ifstream inputFile ( argv[1] );
ofstream outputFile ( argv[2] );

// check if file opening succeeded
if ( !inputFile.is_open() )
{
    cerr << "Could not open the input file\n";
    return 1;
}
else if( !outputFile.is_open() )
{
    cerr << "Could not open the output file\n";
    return 1;
}
//declare a vector of integers
vector<int> numbers;

int numberOfEntries;

//get the first value in the inputFile that has the number of elements in the file
inputFile >> numberOfEntries;

//iterate through the inputFile until there are no more numbers
for( int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; ++i )
{
    //get next number from inputFile
    int number;
    inputFile >> number;

    //store number in the vector
    numbers.push_back( number );
}

//iterate through the vector (need c++11)
for( int n : numbers )
{
    //write to the output file with each number multiplied by 5
    outputFile << (n*5);

    //add a line to the end so the file is readable
    outputFile << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

So I had this code and I compiled it. It would only show me `Incorrect number of arguments`. What is going wrong?

Comment: Wow, I would never try to learn something that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spidey is correct, however, it's important that when you begin programming like this, that you read through the code and break it down into parts you can understand.

```
#include <fstream>  //for file processing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> //to_string
using namespace std;
```

You should recognize these as include directives - using libraries related to I/O, like you expected.

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 ) 
{
    cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This is where the error is being thrown. `argc` is checking how many arguments were provided to the application - if the number is anything other than `3`, the program will return a message, and exit with the result of `1` - a successful program always returns `0` by comparison.

We can double-check this assumption by analyzing the next few lines:

```
//open file at argv[1] ( should be our input file )
ifstream inputFile ( argv[1] );
ofstream outputFile ( argv[2] );
```

See? It's checking for files provided at argument locations `[1]` and `[2]` - our initial assumption is right. The program requires multiple files to be provided at the command line; without them it cannot run. So the program exits early when it realizes it doesn't have the right number of files.

```
// check if file opening succeeded
if ( !inputFile.is_open() )
{
    cerr << "Could not open the input file\n";
    return 1;
}
else if( !outputFile.is_open() )
{
    cerr << "Could not open the output file\n";
    return 1;
}
```

These lines will attempt to open the files, and return an error message and exit early if they cannot be opened (for instance, if they do not exist).

```
//declare a vector of integers
vector<int> numbers;

int numberOfEntries;

//get the first value in the inputFile that has the number of elements in the file
inputFile >> numberOfEntries;

//iterate through the inputFile until there are no more numbers
for( int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; ++i )
{
    //get next number from inputFile
    int number;
    inputFile >> number;

    //store number in the vector
    numbers.push_back( number );
}

//iterate through the vector (need c++11)
for( int n : numbers )
{
    //write to the output file with each number multiplied by 5
    outputFile << (n*5);

    //add a line to the end so the file is readable
    outputFile << "\n";
}
```

This code loops through the `inputFile`, finding numbers, and outputs them into `outputFile`.

So now we know this whole program is an exercise in **reading numbers from a file and writing to another file**. It's a simple I/O example.

```
return 0;
```

Remember when I said a successful program returns `0`? Well here, after all of the code has been run, the program does exactly that.

**Edit:** To directly answer your question, this program requires two files to be provided as filenames. Such an example would be `g++ -o fileExample fileExample.cpp input.txt output.txt` where the `input.txt` file contains rows of numbers, and `output.txt` is created, sitting in the same location as both `input.txt` and .`fileExample.cpp`.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much. I never thought that someone would be such helpful to break this down and walk me through this. I'm so grateful and appreciate your help. I definitely learned something from it.

Comment: @GoodrichClint No problems. We were all novice programmers at some point. After a time, you'll learn to analyze code this way too. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Might you mean `g++ -o fileExample fileExample.cpp` [Enter] `./fileExample input.txt output.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the correct number of arguments. Post what you entered before you hit compile. (Edit: What I said about the program's actual functionality was wrong, I skimmed through lol, the dude above summed it all up better).

Comment: So what would actually work for this code ? To create some file and manipulate them?

Comment: It wants you to give it 2 files and it will display the number of entries in each file.  if ( argc != 3 ){...}  means if there isn't exactly 3 arguments the program will exit.

Comment: Would be something like g++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: so how would I "give it" two files? By asking the user to create them?

Comment: You specify them when you compile and run your program via the commandline. Yes the user will need to have 2 files ready.

Comment: But when I'm "pressing the play button" on a software to run it, it would show errors because I didnt tell the machine to create the file right?

Comment: Nah it's not creating files it's accepting files that are already on your computer. You can't just run it by hitting play because you haven't told it what the files are.

Comment: The txt files have to be in the same folder as the c++ file and you specify them when you compile like I typed above.

Comment: Ah I got it... Thank you Soooooo much!